# I can't knit my documents into PDF in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I have to use RStudio to knit a report in PDF but when I try to knit the document with the packages required in a chunk in Rmarkdown it shows me this error:

```
tlmgr search --file --global '/multirow.sty'

tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Errore: Failed to compile questionario_sulla_responsabilita_222222.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See questionario_sulla_responsabilita_222222.log for more info.
Inoltre: Warning message:
In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
  running command ''tlmgr' search --file --global '/multirow.sty'' had status 1
Execution interrupted
```

how can I fix this? I am using a MacBook Pro

I tried to updated everything I can and I've tried to install everything from the beginning but it jeeps showing me the same error message

Comment: Does running `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` from R help?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56032457/559676

Comment: @YihuiXie: that's a dead link (that question's been deleted). Good news, also for @mariam-el-fath hopefully: the suggestion by @duckmayr did solve this exact same problem for me. Had to first update `tinytex` for it to work, though; the errors `tinytex` provides when it itself it outdated and therefore fails to update/install tinytex aren't exactly helpful :-)

Comment: @Matherion Before https://stackoverflow.com/q/56032457/559676 was deleted (I still have enough reputation on Stack Overflow to see the question), this was my reply there: "Please search for the error message `Remote repository newer than local` at https://yihui.name/tinytex/ and follow the one-liner instruction."

Answer (score 1):

To wrap the comments to the question up and following the solution at [Yihui Xie's page](https://yihui.name/tinytex/#maintenance) - see also [here](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/39) for a discussion.

**In short ...**

```r
tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()
```

**... should do the trick.**

Explanation: It seems that {tinytex}/Texlive is using a rolling package repository that moves to a new version each year while the local installment does not. The reinstallation does move the local installment forward.

An alternative solution: There seems to be an alternative solution that involves making the TexLive package repo un-rolling - i.e. using a fixed version - which might help: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429714/tlmgr-remote-repository-is-newer-than-local-2017-2018)