# Can't knit a page in RStudio

Tags: r, tinytex

I am trying to knit a page in RStudio to PDF so I can make a graph. However, each time I try to knit, I get a different error. The most recent error is the strangest yet. It is not complaining that a directory doesn't exist - it is complaining that it does exist! Why should this be a problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBNjJ.png)

After doing what it said - installing "install_tinytex(force = TRUE)" - I got another error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lrrY.png)

I found a [similar post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099681/i-cant-knit-my-documents-into-pdf-in-rstudio/65728196#65728196)  and used the recommended code, and got yet another error message that "tlmgr" was not found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMyDu.png)

How do I knit my PDF?

Comment: It looks like `install_tinytex(force = TRUE)` didn't complete successfully. To clarify, did you run `install.packages("tinytext")` then run `install_tinytex(force = TRUE)`?

Comment: So I tried that, and then I got this error:

Comment: WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

  - Rtools 3.5 (installed at C:\Rtools)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into �C:/Users/naray/Documents/R/win-library/4.0�
(as �lib� is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tinytext’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: And I followed the instructions, by installing Rtools. But it didn't work and I got the same thing.

Comment: Please edit your question to include those details (delete the comments) and include the output from the command `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Maybe change those "enter image description here" to something more appropriate.